# Gson deserialize interface to its Class implementation

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I am using **Retrofit 2.1.0** with **converter-gson:2.1.0** and separately **gson:2.6.2** in order to customize the serialization/deserialization. The problem is that my POJOs should be hidden behind interfaces and I want to tell Gson which class should be the deserialized interface. And after the deserialization/ serialization Retrofit should be able to return the interface. It would be good if I can take advantage of Generics and easily create a way to tell Gson or Retrofit to serialize/deserialize FooInterface to FooClass.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to create a single deserializer for all of your interfaces and their respective implementations. Follow these steps please:

**1.** Create a base interface that will be extended by your other app interfaces. It is required to create a single deserializer for all of your interfaces and implementation classes.

```
public interface Convertable {
     String getClassName();
}
```

**2.** Create your feature interface and implementation class. As an example, lets name them FooInterface and FooClass. FooInterface should extend Convertable interface.

**FooInterface**

```
public interface FooInterface extends Convertable {

}
```

**FooClass**

```
public class FooClass implements FooInterface {

    // DISCRIMINATOR FIELD
    private final String className;

    private String field1;

    private String field2;

    public FooClass() {
        this.className = getClass().getName();
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

}
```

Note that the value returned by getClassName() is used as discriminator field that will be used in Gson Deserializer (next step) to initialize returnable instance. **I am assuming that your serializer and deserializer class will reside in the same package even if they are in different client and server applications.** If not, then you will need to change getClassInstance() implementation, but would be pretty simple to do so.

**3.** Implement a custom Gson Serializer for all of your application

```
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;

public class ConvertableDeserializer<T extends Convertable> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

    private static final String CLASSNAME = "className";

    public T deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type,
                         final JsonDeserializationContext deserializationContext
                        ) throws JsonParseException {

        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        final JsonPrimitive prim = (JsonPrimitive) jsonObject.get(CLASSNAME);
        final String className = prim.getAsString();
        final Class<T> clazz = getClassInstance(className);
        return deserializationContext.deserialize(jsonObject, clazz);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Class<T> getClassInstance(String className) {
        try {
            return (Class<T>) Class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            throw new JsonParseException(cnfe.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**4.** Register Deserializer with Gson and initialize retrofit

```
 private static GsonConverterFactory buildGsonConverter() {

        final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

        // Adding custom deserializers
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(FooInterface.class, 
                                    new ConvertableDeserializer<FooInterface>());
        final Gson gson = builder.create();

        return GsonConverterFactory.create(myGson);
    }


    public void initRetrofit() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("REST_ENDPOINT")
                .addConverterFactory(buildGsonConverter())
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();
    }
```

You may register the adapter for all of your implementations if you want, using:

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Convertable.class, new ConvertableDeserializer<Convertable>());
```

Comment: I will check this implementation and report.

Comment: I retrieve `NPE` on line  `final String className = prim.getAsString();` of `ConvertableDeserializer` class. And this is obvious. My json does not have `className` field inside it.

Comment: In contrast to what you're writing you never used "getClassName()" as a discriminator in your deserializer.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are willing to take the effort to almost duplicate your entire domain layer using interfaces to hide the implementation detail of your models, I think you will find my answer refresing ;)

You should use [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md) in order to hide any implementation detail in your models. The way it works is pretty simple:

> You write an abstract class, and AutoValue implements it. That is all
>   there is to it; there is literally no configuration.

Adopting this approach you won’t need to create such amount of boilerplate.

And there is this AutoValue Extension called [auto-value-gson](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson), which adds Gson De/Serializer support out of box.

With these simple steps I think your code base will improve substantially.

Comment: Can you provide an example?